# Remove controller Index from URL - Zend Framework 1.12 and Routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework-mvc

In my project I have some pages defined in my index controller, like ie. the About us page. In order for me not to have to type `domain.com/index/about` but `domain.com/about` I have this route:

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static ( 'about', array (
        'controller' => 'Index',
        'action' => 'about'
) );

$router->addRoute ( 'about', $route );
```

It does the job. The problem is that sometimes I have 6 or 7 pages and I have to repeat this route 6 or 7 times. Is there a way for me to do a route that would always remove "`index`" from the url? I would never need a url that has `index` in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write dynamic routes by avoiding the static route type:

```
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        '/:action', 
        array (
            'controller' => 'index',
            'action' => 'index',
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('pages', $route);
```

This will add a route called 'pages' that will match any single action in the index controller. The action and controller defined in this route are merely the defaults and as you are not passing the controller as a variable it will always route to the IndexController. The action will default to indexAction but can be overridden by the route, ie:

```
/about -> IndexController / aboutAction
/contact -> IndexController / contactAction
etc ...
```

Bear in mind this will override any other routes so you need to structure your routing heirachy properly. Routes defined later in the process will override routes already defined.

For more information check the docs: [Zend Framework Standard Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html)